# User place the marker anywhere and the initial marker will disappear

Tags: android

I followed one of the example that people gave me. I have got a marker pin at my current location and also a map is shown. Right now i want to let the user place the marker(pushpin) anywhere he/she likes and the initial marker(pushpin) will disappear after the user pin on other place. Can anyone help?

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc = mapView.getController();

        // obtain gps location
        lm = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(
        //  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,   
            0,
            0,
            locationListener);
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() +
                    " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
        p = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(18);

        // Add a location marker
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listofOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listofOverlays.clear();
        listofOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

        // invalidate() method forces the MapView to be redrawn
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
}

    @Override 
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
        return false;
    }

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // ---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        // ---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.marker);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 48, null);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
        // ---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + p.getLongitudeE6()
                            / 1E6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ontouchevent wil iritate the user since marker will be placed even after a drag function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Geopoint k;
```

oncreate code here:

```
 mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

       mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
```

overlay inner class here:

```
 class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {   

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         k = p;
         mc= mapView.getController();
        mc.animateTo(p);

         mapView.invalidate();
        latitude=p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
        longitude=p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ;
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, 
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this)
                .setTitle("Change city")
                .setMessage("go to the new location?")
                .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }).show();
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   
         if(k!=null)
         {
        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(k, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.marker);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x-10, screenPts.y-34, null); 
         }
        return true;


    }
```

Comment: I realized when i run this map, the marker will not auto point at my current location?

Comment: if u want a marker on current location, u will have to use itemizedoverlay class, that will just  mark ur current location,...will post the code soon

Comment: do you have msn? we talk over there instead?

Comment: Because i have this textbox and a button which leads to the map. What i want to do is that it allows the user to click the map and pin point the location they wants, and they can also fetch that location's address back to the textbox without typing. Can it be done so?

Comment: possible , just use latitude and longitude what u get from onTap ...use those lat, long values in reverse geocoding...post as another question as this solved

Comment: posted. hopefully someone able to solve it man. Anyway thank you so much for your help too.

Comment: @ android_hungry, i am using the codes you gave me. When i first run the map, it can detect my current location but i want the marker to show my current location, then after i can pin point anywhere i like. Can help?

Comment: this code you gave me can pin point any location i want with a marker appeared. But when i first run this map, it will auto detect my location but without a marker. How?

Comment: may be u r using the same lat, long variables u used to detect ur location, sorry cudnt get back .. as thr was no internet conection fr 7 days

Comment: what do you mean by same lat/lng? when i first run this map, it will auto detect my current location but marker didn't show at all. The codes you gave me seems like you have already replaced the marker which mean i can only pin point location i want and marker will appeared or else marker will not appear.

Comment: oh yes, this code wil just draw ur marker where u touch it, i will post the code to mark ur auto detected location soon.. in 3-4 hrs

Comment: ok thank you so much. Another question is all these address are taking for google, but is it possible to take in street directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5406/discussion-between-android-hungry-and-sowhat)

Comment: android_hungry - are you there?